# Save input data in text file

Tags: php, html

Please help me. I am new in php. I am trying for 3 hours but I failed to make this code.
Here is my HTML code. I want to save Name and Password in a text file when users click (Done) button.Please give me the PHP code.

```
<html><head></head>
  <body>
    <form method="post" action="store.php">
    Name: <input id="Pass" type="text"/><br>
    Password: <input id="Pass" type="password"/><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Done"/>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You have to make some sort of attempt yourself, we then help with specific coding problems. Its not a free coding site.

Comment: I am trying for 3 hours but  I failed. And also trying but I am new in php.So please help me

Comment: If this is for a live site, I hope you're protecting that file. Using plain text for password storage is really bad.

Comment: please take a look to the [ask] page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try code below:

```
<html><head></head>
  <body>
    <form method="post" action="store.php">
    Name: <input id="name" name="name" type="text"/><br>
    Password: <input id="Pass" name="pass" type="password"/><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Done"/>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

store.php

```
<?php
    $myfile = fopen("loginData.txt", "a+");
    $txt = "Login name : ".$_POST['name']." -> Password : ".$_POST['pass'];
    fwrite($myfile, $txt);
    fclose($myfile);
?>
```

[Reference](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_create.asp)